# Is "the most edifying of experiences" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

When I search the word 'edifying' in the [Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/edifying), I get the sample sentence:

> Being left in a bar all afternoon with a load of football fans is not the most edifying **of** experiences.

My question is if this sentence is grammatical. What part of speech is the word 'of' in the above sentence? Should it be the following instead?

> Being left in a bar all afternoon with a load of football fans is not the most edifying experiences.

Comment: Why would a dictionary sample sentence not be grammatical? of is a preposition. The most edifying of experiences= the most edifying experience [singular]

Comment: Ah, you are right! It means the most edifying experience (of all the experiences.)

Comment: @TomBennett  "Not the most X of Y" is kind of an idiomatic expression, often used for sarcastic emphasis.   For example, *"I love my friends but listening to them talk about football for hours and hours is **not the most enjoyable of conversations**"*

Comment: It makes perfect sense now. Thanks.